# Django: how to write django signal to update field in django?

Tags: python, django

i want to write a simple django signal that would automatically change the status of a field from **live** to **finished**, when i check a button **completed**.

I have a model that looks like this\

```
class Predictions(models.Model):
    ## other fields are here
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=100, default="in_review")
  

class PredictionData(models.Model):
    predictions = models.ForeignKey(Predictions, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="prediction_data")
    votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    won = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

when i check the **won** button that is in the `PredictionData` model, i want to immediately changes the `status` of the `Prediction` to finished.

NOTE: i have some tuple at the top of the model.

```
STATUS = (
    ("live", "Live"),
    ("in_review", "In review"),
    ("pending", "Pending"),
    ("cancelled", "Cancelled"),
    ("finished", "Finished"),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a signal with:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(pre_save, sender=PredictionData)
def update_prediction(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.won and instance.predictions_id is not None:
        prediction = self.instance.predictions
        prediction.status = 'finished'
        prediction.save(update_fields=('status',))
```

---

> **Note**: Signals are often not a *robust* mechanism. I wrote [an article <sup>[Django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html) that discusses certain problems when using signals. Therefore you should use them only as a last resort.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Prediction` instead of <s>`Predictions`</s>.

Comment: since signal is not a robust mechanism, what is the best approach to solve a problem like this then?

Comment: i thought signal would be the best fit, but i am going through your blog post now, it really showing a lot i did not know

Comment: @DestinyFranks: you can determine the status as a property that queries if there is at least one `PredictionData` with `won=True`. So you can have a field `status_` without finished, and a property `status` that returns `finished` in case there is one with `won`. For example a possible problem with signals if what if you uncheck `won`?

Comment: So there is no way to turn it back to live if there is no won checked using signals?